# Como pausar a execução por um tempo (similar a um "wait" ou "sleep")?

Tags: javascript

Esse código está funcionando e rodando em uma conta existente nesse [site](http://www.l2cr.com/), o que eu quero fazer é: Adicionar uma pausa, um tipo de `While`, `Wait`, `Sleep` ou `ReadyState`, após o login e antes de ir para a nova aba. Essa linha substituiria a linha do `window.close()`.

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <title>L2 CR AUTO LOGIN</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post"    action="http://zionweb.l2cr.com/gamecpc6/index.php">
        <select name="uni_url" id="logServer" class="validate[required]">
          <option  class=""  value="http://zionweb.l2cr.com/gamecpc6/index.php" fbUrl=""  cookieName=""  >
             Personagem1
          </option>
        </select>
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="CHECKBOSS" class="" />
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" value="123456" class="" />
        <input type="hidden" id="loginKid" name="kid" value=""/>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Enter</button>
      </form>

      <script> function myFunction() {
         document.loginForm.submit(); 
         window.close();
         window.open("http://zionweb.l2cr.com/gamecpc6/classes/view_templates/rbs.php");    
      } </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wait,sleep pra que ? qual e a sua intencao o que voce deseja realizar, tente deixar sua pergunta mais objetiva para ter respostas objetivas também, por mais e isto ai Eirc /o

Comment: Preciso de um Wait antes do window.open(); para abrir aba de modo que já tenha sido logada a conta. Caso contrário o login automatico não vai acontecer, pois quando a página é logada logo após abro uma nova aba com o URL que eu quero. Sem o Wait a página vai resultar em não encontrada.

Answer (score 3):

Como nao ficou especificado se voce faz o login da conta por um ajax ou por uma api vou deixar uma solução  simples, porem não a mais aconselhável, voce pode usar o setTimeout para determinar um tempo para executar uma função x, mas acredito que o mais aconselhavel neste caso e analisar qual e o callback possível do ajax/api para poder realizar outra ação.

```js
setTimeout(alerta, 3000); // segundo parámetro e o timing para executar a função 



function alerta() {
  alert("LOL");
}
```

Comment: Highlander no caso não seria melhor um `setTimeout`?

Comment: @SamirBraga Exatamente, o setTimeout seria o mais adequado do que o interval, por que ele executaria apenas uma vez a partir de determinado tempo, valeu pela dica ai, tinha me esquecido!

Comment: Isso mesmo. Achei melhor avisar. :)